# Can Someone explain the order of execution of ORDER BY and SELECT in MySQL when a counting variable is used in SELECT?

Tags: mysql

Suppose the table is:

**Data**

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 9 |

consider the query:

```
SET @r:=0;
SELECT val, @r:=@r+1 as row_num
  FROM Data
  ORDER BY val;
```

Now, I have read that ORDER BY executed after SELECT then this query should give output as below:

| val | row_num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 9 | 5 |

BUT the query gives output as below:

| val | row_num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 9 | 5 |

It is like ORDER BY executed first and then the SELECT executed. How the query is executing actually?

Answer (score 1):

There are several comments to make here.  First, the perceived "order" in your table, as you have pasted it above, does not really exist.  SQL tables are based on unordered tuples of records.  Regarding your observation, the output you are seeing is consistent with the ordering you specified in the `ORDER BY` clause.  If you want the original ordering, then you should maintain a second column which preserves this ordering.

By the way, with the advent of MySQL 8+, you may now take advantage of the analytic functions.  In this case, `ROW_NUMBER` comes in handy:

```sql
SELECT val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) row_num
FROM data
ORDER BY val;
```

The user variables in your question are heading towards being deprecated, so the above version is the way go here.

Comment: Now, I have formatted my question correctly, could you plz see it now and explain to me the execution order? @Tim